# VS Code & Chrome Debugging extension - open new instance of Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code

Using VS Code and the [Chrome debugging extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug) the launch will open a new instance of Chrome if one not already present, or open a new tab if it is (but won't actually work as debugging ports not open). Upon close it closes all tabs.

This is a real PITA if I've got pages open that I want to stay open (e.g. documentation).

Is there a way to get it to always open its own instance of Chrome even if one is already open, and close only that instance on terminate?

i.e. open its own instance of Chrome and leave existing instances alone.

Answer (score 3):

If you specify a `userDataDir` in your `launch.json`, it will launch a new instance of Chrome for you. It will also, somewhat unhelpfully, offer to 'restore pages' everytime it launches after the first time unless you specify the `runtimeArgs` and also `runtimeExecutable`. Here's a sample `launch.json`:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch localhost",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
            "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
        },
        "userDataDir": "${workspaceRoot}.vscode/chrome",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--disable-infobars --disable-session-crashed-bubble"
        ],
        "runtimeExecutable": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
    }
]
```